# Using false with the bitwise OR operator

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

My IDE says `var x = false | isIE;` can be simplified to `var x = isIE;`.

Is it true?

Is there any tricky JavaScript business I should know about?

`isIE` is defined as:

```
function ms_ie() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var old_ie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
    var new_ie = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
    var edge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');

    if ((old_ie > -1) || (new_ie > -1) || (edge > -1)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That’s not true in general unless `isIE` is an integer in [−2147483648, 2147483647]. (Why do you have this expression to begin with?)

Comment: Second part still applies, though – why did you write `false | isIE` to begin with?

Comment: @Ryan  I didn't write the code. Do you know why author used the bitwise OR operator?

Comment: No, there’s never a reason to write code like that. Even if you wanted a shortcut to cast to a 32-bit int (and I can’t imagine it’s being used in that context), that would normally be written as `var x = isIE | 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In boolean algebra `0 | 0 == 0`, `0 | 1 == 1` which can be translated to `false | false == 0` or `false | true == 1`

This is JavaScript so if `isIE` is a `Boolean`, `null` or `undefined` this will do a cast to Integer and you'll always end with `0` or `1`

Comment: Do you know why the bitwise OR operator has been used in this case instead of the logical OR? (I didn't write the code.)

Comment: I'm thinking maybe the bitwise operator was there before a change was made?

Comment: I think you found the reason why!

Comment: @Emilio but I tested and edited my answer, it will be a 0 instead of Boolean

Comment: I was too quick to award you the correct answer! but I'm going to leave it to you to compensate for the two downvotes you got :D

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you want to use a **logical OR** operator, which is `||` (double pipe) not `|` (which, as you've pointed, is a **bitwise OR** operator). In that case the answer is **YES**, as the operation will always skip the `false` value (`false || something === something`).

In terms of **bitwise** operators, you should be aware that they operate on 32-bit values, so if you use bigger values than a 32-bit number can hold, your data will be truncated. You can read more about this [on MDN article about Bitwise Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). **Edit:** to clarify - bitwise operators will cast any value to a **Number** value (to **32-bit Integer**, to be specific).

Comment: Do you know why the bitwise OR operator has been used in this case instead of the logical OR? (I didn't write the code.)

Comment: No, you should as the author of that piece of code. It might be the case that the author did not know about the differences himself.

Comment: Then why don't you contact the author if you really want to know that? He or she is the only person that could answer that question.

Comment: @Emilio In general when dealing with logical operations, it doesn't make sense to use bitwise or. It's neither faster in any way (as it has to perform a conversion to integer value), nor it's more readable (because you have to know about all the pitfalls to use it properly). My only guess is that the author either did not know about the difference, or they were trying to save up one single character of the code (either for bandwidth reasons, or it's was a code golf challenge).

Comment: The thing is that JavaScript does coercion to integer when you use a bit wise operator like I've explained in my answer

Comment: @r1verside yes, I know that - it's in the second part of my answer.

Comment: @mdziekon you're talking about integers and overflow of integers capacity. See my edited answer, that's what I'm talking about

Comment: @r1verside to me the "they operate on 32-bit values" part was pretty clear (plus the linked article) that it means integer values, but I've edited my answer to make it even more clear.